# Substrings in Javascript with substr()

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to use Substring in Javascript. But despite my searches, i have an error : substr seems to be unknown...

```
function confirm_ticket(idAgir,TempsEstime) {

    var str = TempsEstime;
    var strConcatenate = TempsEstime.substr(0, 2) + ":" + TempsEstime.substr(2, 2);

    alert("confirmer le temps de maintenance de " + strConcatenate + " min pour le ticket " + idAgir);
}
```

Is there anything wrong in this ?
thanks in advance

Comment: what is the type of TempsEstime?

Comment: What is related with c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for substring()

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

```
function confirm_ticket(idAgir,TempsEstime) {

    var str = TempsEstime;
    var strConcatenate = TempsEstime.substring(0, 2) + ":" + TempsEstime.substring(2, 2);

    alert("confirmer le temps de maintenance de " + strConcatenate + " min pour le ticket " + idAgir);
}
```

Comment: [Better documentation, for the sake of humanity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Answer (score 3):

The substr and substring methods in JavaScript are bound to the String object, so they only work on string types.  Use the `typeof` keyword to determine what time you are applying the methods to.

substr takes two arguments:  1) which index to start, 2) how many characters

substring takes two arguments: 1)which index to start, 2) which index to end

EDIT: The white space formatting was jumbled.

Comment: +1 Why the downvote? its the only answer to understand .substr is perfectly fine and that the only cause of the error is a type error

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `substring()` method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="Hello world!";
 document.write(str.substring(3)+"<br />");
 document.write(str.substring(3,7));

</script>
```

FROM: [JavaScript substring() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [.substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) and see if that works.

Another thing to notice, make sure the type of 'TempsEstime' is a string.